# How to bypass some piece of code from JTA transaction

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, jms, jta

I am using JTA UserTransaction to perform some database and JMS related activity.

The problem goes as below.

1.Start UsertTransaction

2.Perform DB search operation

3.Perform DB updated operation

4.Perform JMS send and recieve operation----> Problematic work flow

5.Perform DB updated operation

6.Commit the transaction.

The 4th step is creating problem as the message sent would not be persisted in the queue until the transaction is committed and due to this JMS receive functionality is broken.

Step 4 cant be performed before stating the JTA transaction as there is  lot of dependency on the other steps.

Is there any way I can handle this type of situation.IS there any way to bypass transaction for step4? Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: perform step4 in another transaction...

Comment: I guess nested transaction is not supported.

Comment: No. If you throw an exception from step4 and let it bubble, then the step4 transaction and the "main" transaction will both rollback. But if step5 or 6 makes the main transaction rollback, then it won't affect the step4 transaction which will already be committed.